# Vite installation errror[plugin:vite:react-babel] Cannot redefine property: File

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, vite

[plugin:vite:react-babel] Cannot redefine property: File
C:/Users/Akash Shankar/OneDrive/Desktop/Final_year project/New folder (2)/reactcurrencyexchange/1111/src/main.jsx
at Function.defineProperty ()
at Object. (C:\Users\Akash Shankar\OneDrive\Desktop\Final_year project\New folder (2)\reactcurrencyexchange\1111\node_modules@babel\core\lib\index.js:7:8)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\Akash Shankar\OneDrive\Desktop\Final_year project\New folder (2)\reactcurrencyexchange\1111\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\helpers\config-api.js:16:14)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14
Click outside, press Esc key, or fix the code to dismiss.
You can also disable this overlay by setting server.hmr.overlay to false in vite.config.js.

I'm encountering issues while trying to set up a React environment using Vite. Despite having Node version 20.11.1 installed, I'm still facing problems with the Vite installation process. Can anyone offer guidance or assistance?